# Openshift Jenkins and Ruby2

Tags: jenkins, openshift, ruby-2.0

Is it possible to host a jenkins server on openshift with ruby2?
I'd like openshift to host my jenkins server, and have jenkins run rake test on my rails app, using ruby2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with OpenShift Online. You can create a Jenkins server app, and enable Jenkins CI for your Ruby app on another gear, which will create a Jenkins project for you (which can be configured further using Jenkins' web interface).